# Android´s MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Tags: android

I am building an app with API level 19 and I am using:

```
 // download the file
                input = connection.getInputStream();
                fOut = openFileOutput("example.json",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

it says that "The field Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated", is there some alternative or adding the @SuppressWarning there is not problems to use it? Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Making files world-readable can be a security flaw, which is why Google no longer endorses the practice. In particular, I cannot think of a reason why a JSON file would need to be world-readable.

If you want an app to make file content available to other apps, [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to download a file each 4 hours from url to refresh my app. I don´t know what is the best option to do this because not all phones have SdCard and I don´t know if I have to use an Activity, can you help me?

Comment: @user3733523: "I want to download a file each 4 hours from url to refresh my app" -- then use `MODE_PRIVATE` instead of `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`. "not all phones have SdCard" -- you are not saving the file on "SdCard". "I don´t know if I have to use an Activity" -- the only way an `Activity` will run every four hours is if the user chooses to manually launch it every four hours. `AlarmManager`, `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, and an `IntentService` would be the route to go for automation.

Comment: Tank you very much, very kind

Comment: This anwser really needs more upvotes. After following the tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html i finaly got it to work. Thanks, man.

Comment: @DaMachk: Note that `FileProvider` alone has some compatibility issues with some poorly-written clients. You may want to blend in [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper), such as in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider).